# The threat of video metadata

Tags: malware

There are various old questions on stack exchange which say that malicious code in file metadata can potentially be executed when the file is opened ([here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18086/virus-encoded-in-video), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675941/how-can-a-virus-exist-in-an-image), and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/357869/is-it-possible-to-store-arbitrary-data-in-an-image-file) for example). They are all from a few years ago however, is this still a valid threat with today's video players? If so, what steps can I take to make sure that my videos are safe to play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try heuristic scanning tools. It's basically putting it all in a sandbox and watch it do it's thing. IF you're adventurous an technically inclined, you also can scan it with forensics tools and get that data visible for inspection. I found a cool book in google books [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=lRjO8opcPzIC&pg=PA307&lpg=PA307&dq=forensic%20programs%20to%20scan%20files%20for%20viruses&source=bl&ots=aWWNncwzYr&sig=guYDDOnE06cEn_CntIAor8H7REc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bc_hU9PdKcS3yASMu4HQBA&ved=0CGsQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=forensic%20programs%20to%20scan%20files%20for%20viruses&f=false). If that's too long winded, you could just turn off data execution on your box and any auto run features. This would give you the breathing room to scan the file before deployment and use. Now, let's say you're one of those really paranoid types. Well, get yourself virtualbox, configure a guest, slap on deepfreeze, secure it and tweek it.