# Wifi Cloud Storage

Tags: cloud-computing, storage

If you move files from an infected machine to a Wi-Fi Cloud storage, then move the same files from the Wi-Fi storage to a non infected machine, could you infect your new non infected machine?

Comment: Are you seeing that wifi or cloud storage is a particular threat? Or could your concerns also be expressed, "if you move files from an infected computer to a storage device and then to a clean computer, con the clean computer get infected?"

Answer (score 2):

If you copy an infected file from an infected machine to a cloud service, then copy it to the new (clean) machine, it will not automatically become infected. It will only be infected again if the user opens one of the infected files.

I recommend ensuring that you do not copy any exe, dll, sys, scr, bat, pif, lnk, com, or other executable files over. You can also do a malware scan of the disk after you copy files over in order to detect the malware on disk in case you copied it accidentally, in order to minimise the probability that you re-infect the machine. You should also ensure that all software on the new machine is fully up to date (particularly Windows Update).

Comment: The only files I will be moving to and from the Wi Fi Cloud storage is Videos and pictures.
can video and pictures files be infected?
if I move the file (that may or may not be infected) from the cloud to the non infected computer as long as I don't open that file, the non infected machine is safe, Right? which would mean I could scan it first to check?

Comment: This is not at all what you asked in your question. I think you need to edit your question to include what you are trying to ask. You have several different types of questions you are trying to ask at the same time.

Comment: I don't think @Avianx85 should open that first part as a separate question because it is answered here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18086/virus-encoded-in-video