# Could there be malware in a video on twitter?

Tags: malware, html, video, twitter

I don't know anything about security.

I want to download the videos I like from twitter. And I'm not going to do it by writing a program. I will manually find the necessary link in the html document and download it. Could there be malware in the video I downloaded?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The answer from 2012 is about video files. The videos on social media today aren't really downloadable files, so I find this a bit different question.

Comment: "I want to download the videos I like from twitter... I will manually find the necessary link in the html document and download it." I'm not sure what you mean here. Usually Twitter doesn't embed a direct link to a full video file. Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

While a video file could have been "*crafted to exploit a vulnerability in the codec or media player*" (from an [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/18088/70406) of Polynomial), the video upload features on social media sites typically re-encode the video in a way that would remove such exploits.

Generally social media services provide videos as streams instead of downloads. Twitter does not have video download buttons nor "*the necessary link in the html document*". Instead, the video is provided in small (~150k `video/mp4`) chunks from `https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/*/pu/vid/*/*/*/*.m4s`.

Software exists that can put these chunks together, allowing them to be saved as files. As it creates a completely new file it is less likely that any attempts to exploit a vulnerability in a codec or in a media player would survive. It is not entirely impossible, but very unlikely, and would require a highly advanced attack.